PBI Dynamic Variance Graph only selected Months for YOY Average
GOAL: Create a measure that will allow stakeholders to see the average YoY for only the selected fiscal months and years
Here is what the chart looks like (actual percentages redacted):
line chart with y-axis % W/F, x-axis fiscal months and lines separated by fiscal year
The chart is already dynamic, so users can select any combination of fiscal years 2019-2024, and the slider will let them highlight any combination of months. The calculations just aren't working.
I will show you what I want the numbers to do in table form.
NOTE: Fiscal_year is formatted as a whole number form of 'YYYY'
Fiscal_Month is formated as a whole number for the month number
Fiscal_Month_Start is formatted as a Date in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format



%W/F
%W/F PY Selected
Variance
Fiscal_Month_Start




5%
12%
-7%
2024-06-01


7%
4%
3%
2024-05-01


2%
18%
-16%
2024-04-01


11%
6%
5%
2024-03-01


4%
8%
-4%
2024-02-01


10%
3%
7%
2024-01-01


6%
13%
-7%
2023-12-01


5%
6%
1%
2023-11-01


8%
11%
3%
2023-10-01


20%
15%
5%
2023-09-01


12%
4%
8%
2023-08-01


10%
3%
7%
2023-07-01


2%
11%
-9%
2023-06-01


4%
12%
-8%
2023-05-01


18%
11%
7%
2023-04-01


6%
15%
-9%
2023-03-01


8%
4%
-4%
2023-02-01


3%
5%
2%
2023-01-01


13%
11%
2%
2022-12-01


6%
7%
-1%
2022-11-01


11%
4%
7%
2022-10-01


15%
17%
2%
2022-09-01


4%
6%
2%
2022-08-01


3%
8%
5%
2022-07-01


11%
21%
-10%
2022-06-01


12%
9%
3%
2022-05-01


11%
5%
6%
2022-04-01


15%
8%
7%
2022-03-01


4%
12%
-8%
2022-02-01


5%
1%
4%
2022-01-01



That is the straight table, if I have all fiscal months selected and I have selected the years 2022, 2023, and 2024.
[% W/F] = CALCULATE(DIVIDE(SUM('W/F Data'[w_f_flag]), SUM('W/F Data'[rn])), 'W/F Data'[course_end_dt] <= TODAY())

[% W/F PY Selected] = This is the measure I'm having trouble with, it should be the prior fiscal year's [% W/F] value for the selected months and years

[Variance] = IF(ISBLANK([% W/F PY Selected]) || ISBLANK([% W/F]), BLANK(), [% W/F] - [% W/F PY Selected])

I am planning on adding to [Variance] ---> IF(MIN(SELECTEDVALUE(Fiscal_year)) = Fiscal_year, blank(), ....) Because I want to only calculate variance between the lines shown.
This part I can get to work, and I can get the average variance to show in a card on the page above the graph. The issues come if I try to skip months and/or years.
For example, If I select fiscal months 2-5 and fiscal years 2024 and 2022, then I want this to happen with the numbers:



%W/F
%W/F PY Selected
Variance
Fiscal_Month_Start




5%


2024-06-01


7%
12%
-5%
2024-05-01


2%
11%
-9%
2024-04-01


11%
15%
-4%
2024-03-01


4%
4%
0
2024-02-01


10%


2024-01-01


6%


2023-12-01


5%


2023-11-01


8%


2023-10-01


20%


2023-09-01


12%


2023-08-01


10%


2023-07-01


2%


2023-06-01


4%


2023-05-01


18%


2023-04-01


6%


2023-03-01


8%


2023-02-01


3%


2023-01-01


13%


2022-12-01


6%


2022-11-01


11%


2022-10-01


15%


2022-09-01


4%


2022-08-01


3%


2022-07-01


11%


2022-06-01


12%


2022-05-01


11%


2022-04-01


15%


2022-03-01


4%


2022-02-01


5%


2022-01-01



And it will give me the average of just the variance numbers shown.
I have tried multiple summarize tables, and calculations. This was my most recent attempt:
[% W/F PY Selected] = 
VAR _selectedY = SELECTEDVALUE('W/F Data'[fiscal_year])
VAR _selectedM = SELECTEDVALUE('W/F Data'[fiscal_month])
var _previousYM = CALCULATE(MAX('W/F Data'[fiscal_year]), ALLSELECTED('W/F Data'), 
                            KEEPFILTERS('W/F Data'[fiscal_year] < _selectedY), KEEPFILTERS('W/F Data'[fiscal_month] = _selectedM))
var result = CALCULATE([% W/F], ALLSELECTED('W/F Data'), 'W/F Data'[fiscal_year] = _previousYM && 'W/F Data'[fiscal_month] = _selectedM)
RETURN
result

I've gotten a couple where I think it will work, but I get an error that it can't calculate that much or I get an error that it expects the date to be continuous. I've also tried changing dateadd to edate in a few different experiments.
UPDATE:
I'm getting closer! This code is dynamic for month selection. It just breaks down when it comes to selecting non-consecutive years, like only selecting 2023 and 2021, but it's a step forward!
% W/F PY Selected = 
VAR _thisMonth = SELECTEDVALUE('W/F Data'[fiscal_month])
VAR _thisYear = SELECTEDVALUE('W/F Data'[fiscal_year])
VAR _lastDateAvailable = CALCULATETABLE(LASTNONBLANK('W/F Data'[fiscal_month_start], [% W/F]), 'W/F Data'[fiscal_month] = _thisMonth, 'W/F Data'[fiscal_year] = _thisYear)
VAR _PYSelected = DATEADD(_lastDateAvailable, -1, YEAR)
VAR _wfPY = CALCULATE([% W/F], _PYSelected = 'W/F Data'[fiscal_month_start])
RETURN
_wfPY

Just in case you're looking for an update, here is some more code I have been working with. I'm now stuck on not being able to get the table to select the next non-blank date. I was going to change the dateadd functions to be current selected year - next non-blank fiscal year, but I can't get it to return what the next non-blank fiscal year is.
% W/F PY Selected = 
VAR _thisMonth = SELECTEDVALUE('W/F Data'[fiscal_month])
VAR _thisYear = SELECTEDVALUE('W/F Data'[fiscal_year])
VAR _lastDateAvailable = CALCULATETABLE(LASTNONBLANK('W/F Data'[fiscal_month_start], [% W/F]), 'W/F Data'[fiscal_month] = _thisMonth, 'W/F Data'[fiscal_year] = _thisYear)
VAR _yearavailable = YEAR(_lastDateAvailable)
VAR _PYSelected = DATEADD(_lastDateAvailable, -1, YEAR)
VAR _PriorYear = _yearavailable - 1
VAR _NexttoLastDate = CALCULATETABLE(LASTNONBLANK('W/F Data'[fiscal_month_start], [% W/F]), 'W/F Data'[fiscal_month] = _thisMonth, 'W/F Data'[fiscal_year] <= _PriorYear)
VAR _PY2Selected = DATEADD(_lastDateAvailable, -2, YEAR)
VAR _PY3Selected = DATEADD(_lastDateAvailable, -3, YEAR)
VAR _PY4Selected = DATEADD(_lastDateAvailable, -4, YEAR)
VAR _PY5Selected = DATEADD(_lastDateAvailable, -5, YEAR)
VAR _wfPY = CALCULATE([% W/F], _PYSelected = 'W/F Data'[fiscal_month_start])


RETURN
_NexttoLastDate


I just tried this and got an error about it taking too many resources and to try and add filters:
[ % W/F PY Selected] = % W/F PY Variance =
VAR _thisMonth = FILTER( ALL('W/F Data'), 'W/F Data'[fiscal_month] = SELECTEDVALUE('W/F Data'[fiscal_month]) && 'W/F Data'[fiscal_year] = SELECTEDVALUE('W/F Data'[fiscal_year]))
VAR result = AVERAGEX(SUMMARIZE(_thisMonth, 'W/F Data'[fiscal_month_start], "wfPY", CALCULATE([% W/F], DATEADD('W/F Data'[fiscal_month_start], -1, YEAR))), [wfPY])
RETURN
result
